# Execute a application in EC2 instance using cmd ssh from local PC

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, cmd

I have created a EC2 instance in AWS. I have acquired the cmd of the windows EC2 instance using ssh into it.

the following is the command i have used to login,
`ssh <user-name>@<ip-address`
Eg: `ssh admin@3.11.121.1`

I need to execute a python script using cmd which is present in EC2 instance. `python app.py`

The script is not being executed. I have tried to execute `explorer.exe`, which is also not working.

Kindly provide me with a possible solution

Comment: `ssh blah@blah.com -c "python app.py"` maybe will do what you want depending on your ssh client ... do they have windows ec2? if its not windows it wont run any .exe ...

Comment: yes, its a Windows 2019 server EC2 instance.  I have tried executing what you had shared. Its not working. Whenever i try to execute a python or an application, the cursor starts blinking and no response is received

Comment: You're connecting to a Windows 2019 Server via SSH and trying to execute `python app.py`? Why would you connect to Windows via SSH when it isn't supported natively by Windows? In either case, is Python installed? If you're executing it and the cursor blinks then Python is installed but the script is waiting for something or locking up with no return error. Try adding some debugging to the script to see where the issue might be.

Comment: that may have something to do with what the app.py is doing. Do you get an output if you ran `ssh blah@blah.com "dir"` or `ssh blah@blah.com "ls"`

Comment: @recoilnetworks its not just about python. Every .exe commands is not being executed.
For example, if i try "explorer.exe" in actual cmd of EC2 instance, it works. But if i try the same by acquiring the shell using ssh, nothing is outputted. I hope u get my point

Comment: @puzzledgear yes, commands like dir, mkdir, del, copy con are working fine. 
I am unable to launch any application or executing commands like 'python app.py' is not working

Comment: if you're able to run `ssh blah@blah.com "dir"`, then the problem is with the app.py. We don't know what it does? Does the app.py print anything? If you login to the ec2 instance and ran it from the terminal does it prompt you for anything?

Comment: if i login to the ec2 instance and execute the same file using cmd, it works prefectly fine. 
the problem is with executing applications/scripts using ssh of ec2 instance.

Comment: This is not a problem with `The script is not being executed` through ssh. Executing a command from ssh clearly works when executing `dir` command. That means there is something going on with your `app.py`. You can tell us what your app.py is doing and maybe we can help

Comment: @puzzledgear let's forget about running a python script. In simple terms, `explorer.exe` command is not being executed through ssh. Can anyone pls explain, how it be achieved ?

Comment: That's the premise on what the question is. Why are you trying to execute explorer.exe from ssh, what's your intention? What do you mean by `.I have tried to execute explorer.exe, which is also not working.`

Comment: It won't bring up explorer.exe windows on your HOST computer (where you're running ssh from) if that's what you expect.

Comment: Look into it step by step, `ssh admin@3.11.121.1 explorer.exe`. This means you first logged in to 3.11.121 as admin user. Then you execute explorer.exe which a process started inside 3.11.121.1 not in your host computer that means you won't see explorer.exe coming up from your Host computer. The same thing here:  `ssh admin@3.11.121.1 dir`, it logs in as admin, executes `dir` in 3.11.121.1, returns the output.

Comment: Same can be said here in `ssh admin@3.11.121.1 app.py` - log in as admin, execute app.py inside 3.11.121.1. In your question `it's not executing` is not enough information. Give us more details, so we can help. In what way is it not executing? How did you know it's not executing? What do you expect? Is there an error message? Does it hang? All I can make is speculations about what your app.py is doing. If it's hanging, I can speculate that the app.py is waiting for INPUT, you can't pass an input by simply running `ssh admin@host app.py`.

Comment: I can speculate that it DOES execute, and now the process is attached to your hosts terminal. Imagine `ssh admin@3.11.121.1 endlessloop.py`, and the script is just a while loop. I know that it executes but then the prompt will just blink unless I ctrl+C it. Executing a command through SSH is not equivalent to logging in, execute the command, run it in the background (or here's my answers to app.py prompt). Here's another suggestion for debugging, create a helloworld.py script that just does "print('helloworld')". Execute it through ssh `ssh admin@<ip> helloworld.py`, does it work?

Comment: Sorry let me clarify this `Executing a command through SSH is not equivalent to logging in, execute the command, run it in the background (or here's my answers to app.py prompt)`. What I meant was that it's not the same as logging in and having an "INTERACTIVE" session with the remote hosts. So in my endlesslopp.py example, the process will never finish because it's endless, so it will never return a prompt (just blinks). I think the same can be said for app.py.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the issues.

If we try to execute a GUI application in the EC2 instance using ssh, the GUI wont show up but the process is being executed in the background, we can ensure that in task manager.

Also, to execute a .exe file or batch file or a python script which triggers a UI application, we need to change certain settings in firewall.